# Magento Password Field is missing when installing magento

Tags: php

Almost I've been install magento 5 to 10 times on my localhost server. but there is no option to insert admin username and admin password. my question is where is the admin username and password fields?, when installing magento username and password.

Comment: How far along the installation process have you got? The admin creation is done as one of the last steps.

Comment: I've never find this step

Comment: they cannot ask me to insert admin username and admin password.

Comment: which version you are using

Answer (score 1):

First page is USERNAME + PASSWORD from your DATABASE.

After that you can setup your admin account. But you have to finish installation without errors to get the last install page. Do you get errors while installing or a never finishing installer ?

Greating and Happy Hacking !